# PL/SQL: regexp_like for string not start with letters

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

For regexp_like running on Oracle database 11g. I want a pattern to match a string not start with AM or AP,the string is usually few letters followed by an underscore and other letters or underscore.
For example :

String : AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX    [false]
String : AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX    [false]
String : BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX    [true]
String : A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD    [true]
String : A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED    [true]
String : MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX    [true]

Can you make this pattern ?

My current solution doesn't work:

```
BEGIN
    IF regexp_like('AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX','[^(AM)(AP)]+_.*') THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

why you need regexp why you not use simple substr?

```
with t1 as
 (select 'AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX' as f1
    from dual
  union all
  select 'AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX'
    from dual
  union all
  select 'BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX'
    from dual
  union all
  select 'A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD'
    from dual
  union all
  select 'A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED'
    from dual
  union all
  select 'MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX' from dual
  union all
  select null from dual
  union all
  select '1' from dual)

select f1,
       case
           when substr(f1, 1, 2) in ('AM', 'AP') then
            'false'
           else
            'true'
       end as check_result
  from t1
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm calling a API procedure which needs to pass a regexp pattern as a parameter to make it work. And there are already dozens of other patterns defined, I CANNOT hard code the strings, it's dynamically input.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of patterns then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE strings ( string ) AS
          SELECT 'AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE patterns ( pattern ) AS
          SELECT '^AM' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '^AP' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Negative Matches:
SELECT string
FROM   strings s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       patterns p
       ON ( REGEXP_LIKE( string, pattern ) )
WHERE  p.pattern IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9/0)**:

```
|            STRING |
|-------------------|
| BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |
| A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD |
| A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED |
| MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- Positive Matches:
SELECT DISTINCT
       string
FROM   strings s
       INNER JOIN
       patterns p
       ON ( REGEXP_LIKE( string, pattern ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9/1)**:

```
|            STRING |
|-------------------|
| AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |
| AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- All Matches:
SELECT string,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( string,
                              ( SELECT LISTAGG( pattern, '|' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY NULL )
                                FROM   patterns )
                            )
            THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
            END AS Matched
FROM   strings s
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9/2)**:

```
|            STRING | MATCHED |
|-------------------|---------|
| AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |    True |
| AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX |    True |
| BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |   False |
| A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD |   False |
| A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED |   False |
| MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |   False |
```

If you want to pass the pattern as a single string then:

**Query 4**:

```
-- Negative Matches:
SELECT string
FROM   strings
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE( string, '^(AM|AP)' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9/3)**:

```
|            STRING |
|-------------------|
| BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |
| A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD |
| A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED |
| MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |
```

**Query 5**:

```
-- Positive Matches:
SELECT string
FROM   strings
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( string, '^(AM|AP)' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9/4)**:

```
|            STRING |
|-------------------|
| AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |
| AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX |
```

**Query 6**:

```
-- All Matches:
SELECT string,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( string, '^(AM|AP)' )
            THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
            END AS Matched
FROM   strings
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/79eb7/9/5)**:

```
|            STRING | MATCHED |
|-------------------|---------|
| AM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |    True |
| AP_HTCEVOBLKHSPBX |    True |
| BM_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |   False |
| A_HTCEVODSAP_DSSD |   False |
| A_HTCEVOB_A_CDSED |   False |
| MP_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX |   False |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^([B-Z][A-Z]*|A[A-LNOQ-Z]?|A[A-Z]{2,})_[A-Z_]+$
```

The idea is to describe all possible start of the string.

```
(                 # a group
    [B-Z][A-Z]*   # The first character is not a "A"
  |               # OR
    A[A-LNOQ-Z]?  # a single "A" or a "A" followed by a letter except "P" or "M"
  |               # OR
    A[A-Z]{2,}    # a "A" followed by more than 1 letter
)                 # close the group
```

`^` and `$` are anchors and means "start of the string" and "end of the string"

Comment: May I ask what does the '?!' mean? Thanks

Comment: @Frank: `(?!..)` is a negative lookahead that means "not followed by", but I have removed it since PLSQL doesn't seems to support this feature. refresh your page.

Comment: It's not working, I tested 'D_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX'  'AD_HTCEVOBLKHS_BX' which should return true, but both return false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just this:

```
not regexp_like( field, '^(AM_)|^(AP_)' )
```

As it is a LIKE function you don't need any more on the regex expression.